# Retrieving the starting memory addresses of the blocks of a file

Tags: java, c, operating-system

A hard disk is broken in to blocks and every file stored on the hard disk is broken into that size of block and stored on the hard disk.

e.g.
Consider a 1MB file and the block size is 512 bytes, then the file's first block is stored at `0x121454` and second block at `0x846132`.
I need to obtain `0x121454` and `0x846132`. I want to use Java.
If not in Java then can C be used? If so with the help of jni I can implement that.

In linux inode block has the details of all the memory addresses but not aware of window.

Comment: punctuation, my friend; , ...

Comment: Some good reading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635598/java-how-to-store-and-retrieve-memory-address-like-in-c

Comment: Your title does not match your question. And some formatting would definitely help to solicit some answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in pure Java.

You probably can't do this in C / C++ either ... unless you are running a privileged application that can access the "raw" device file in Linux (or the Windows equivalent).

And even then, you'd need to implement a whole stack of code that understands the file system structure at the disc block level, and can do all of the calculations.

And those calculations are far, far more complicated than your question envisages.  There are multiple file system formats to deal with, and then there are the mappings from virtual disk block numbers to the level of physical disk / platter / track / sector addressing.

---

And even once you've achieved this, you can't use the information for anything much:

1. It would be dangerous to try to write files using physical disk addresses.  One mistake and you've trashed the file system.  (In fact, it is impossible to do safely unless you unmount the file system first ... because there's no way your application can coordinate with what the OS is doing.)
2. Even reading would be difficult to do reliably, because the OS could be writing to the file while you are reading, and that could be changing the disc address of the file's contents.